# Is there a protobuf message which supports/extends java.lang.Exception?

Tags: exception, protocol-buffers

We are trying represent a CustomException into protobuf format -

```
public class CustomRestException extends RuntimeException {

private CustomRestErrorMessage customRestErrorMessage;
 public CustomRestException (CustomRestErrorMessage customRestErrorMessage, Throwable   cause) {
    super(cause);
    this.customRestErrorMessage= customRestErrorMessage;
 }
 public CustomRestException (CustomRestErrorMessage customRestErrorMessage) {
     this.customRestErrorMessage= customRestErrorMessage;
 }
}

public class CustomRestErrorMessage implements Serializable {

  private String causeMessage = "";
  private String errorCode = "";
  private String errorMessage = "";
  private String errorSubCode = "";
  private String stackTrace = "";
}
```

And here is the CustomRestExceptionProtos.proto file

```
option java_package = "com.company.my.exception"; 
option java_outer_classname = "CustomRestExceptionProtos"; 

message CustomRestProtoException
 {
    required CustomRestProtoErrorMessage customRestErrorMessage = 1;
 }

message CustomRestProtoErrorMessage
 {
    required string errorCode = 1;
    required string errorMessage = 2;
    required string errorSubCode = 3;
    required string causeMessage = 4;     
    required string stackTrace= 5;
 }
```

Is it possible to represent this "CustomRestExceptionProtos" as type a java.lang.Exception in .proto file ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want the Java class generated from your `CustomRestProtoException` message type to drive from `java.lang.Exception`. I think the only way you might achieve this is by writing a plugin to extend the java code generation:

http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/reference/java-generated.html#plugins

An alternate and simpler approach would be to introduce a wrapper Java Exception subclass to hold the `CustomRestProtoException` object:

```
public class CustomRestException extends Exception
{
    private CustomRestProtoException exception;

    // usual constructors etc.
}
```